# sas difference between sum and +?

Tags: sum, sas

```
data whatever;
 infile '';
 input price cost;
 <statement>;
run;
```

In `<statement>`, what's the difference between using `total = sum(total,cost)` and `total = total + cost` ?

Comment: do you mean `total=total+cost;` or `total+cost;` as the second option?

Comment: I want to create a running total. Isn't it `variable + expression` ?

Comment: It is; just wanted to clarify what you were intending to do (since you didn't explain that in the question).

Comment: I was confused by these two statements. First I learnt `total+cost` and I kept using it. But putting `total = sum(total,cost)` into it won't lead to an error. So I wonder if they're equivalent.

Comment: `total+cost` is faster to type (and avoids having to include `retain total;`).  Otherwise equivalent - like in c++, you can say `x=x+1;` or `x++;` equivlanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differnce can be seen below:

If you want to calculate cumulative total , you should use sum statement.

total = sum(total,cost) /* its a sum function */

total+cost /* its a sum statement,the form is variable+expression */

Here :

**"total"** specifies the name of the accumulator variable, which contains a numeric value.

1) The variable(total in this case) is automatically set to 0 before SAS reads the first observation. The variable's value is retained from one iteration to the next, as if it had appeared in a RETAIN statement.

2) To initialize a sum variable to a value other than 0, include it in a RETAIN statement with an initial value.

and

**"Cost"** is an expression

1) The expression is evaluated and the result added to the accumulator variable.

2) SAS treats an expression that produces a missing value as zero.

A sum statement is differ from a sum function in a way that a sum statement retains the value which it has calculated earlier.

However,
The sum statement is equivalent to using the SUM function and the RETAIN statement, as shown here:

```
retain total 0;
total=sum(total,cost);
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate explanation.

Comment: You are most welcome , but ideally the topic header should be difference between "sum statement" and "sum function", however +1 for nicely putting up this question.

Answer (score 2):

<s>You'd probably have trouble with either of those if you actually including it after the `input` statement.</s>

The information that ProgramFOX posted is correct, but if you're asking about the difference between these three statements, there's a little more to it:

```
total = sum(total,cost);
total + cost;
```

The second of these implies a `retain total;` statement and will also treat nulls as zero.  You run into the null problem when you're using this type of expression:

```
total = total + cost;
```

Comment: Good point, Joe.  I was guess I was imagining code coming after a `datalines`.